# REST call in MULE ESB

Tags: java, json, rest, mule

Rest call is implemented in Java. same thing i want to implement in mule,
 **Java code is below:**

```
URL url = new URL(RestUriConstants.BUSINESS_PROCESS_BASE + businessProcessName);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
writer.write(data);
writer.flush();
```

in mule i'm sending two things 
 **1. URL
 
 2. pay load**

the json is like below:
**{"url":"http://mysystem.com:8080/rest/processData","param":{"claimNo":"9","status":"open", "customerName":"Rajesh"}}**

how can i pass that url dynamically, as well as i need to pass param value into the rest call..

**---UPDATE----**

payload value is like
**"action=start&params={'input':#[json:param]}&createTask=false&parts=all"**

example:

```
<set-payload value="action=start&params={'input':#[json:param]}&createTask=false&parts=all"/>
```

but it is giving error.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do rest calls with a dynamic url in Mule, you just need to set the json as payload first, and then

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://#[url]" method="POST" />
```

with variable url defining the url.

If your payload is the above json string, you can do

```
<set-variable variableName="url" value="#[json:url]"/>
```

and

```
<set-payload value="#[json:param]"/>
```

before the outbound. Note that in this case you have to strip the "http://" url prefix in the outbound like this:

```
address="http://#[url.substring(7)]"
```

Hope this gets you started, your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: try "username:password@#[url]"

Comment: Thanks Anton, it is working fine. but i need authentication, my java code like this:: static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
   return (new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray()));
  }
 }
i added password="admin" user="admin" in <http:outbound-endpoint> but that is not working.

Comment: i need to append 'action=start&params={input:#[json:param]}&createTask=false&parts=all' in payload tag, how can i?